# How to convert C library to different ABIs using cmake

Tags: android, c, cmake, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I am trying to create shared libraries from the [c_speech_features C library](https://github.com/Cwiiis/c_speech_features) for the different Android ABIs. I have downloaded the Android NDK and have tried to follow the cmake instructions for ['Cross Compiling for Android'](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-android) to create the `.so` library.

Steps Tried:

1. Downloaded [the library source code](https://github.com/Cwiiis/c_speech_features)
2. Altered the `CMakeLists.txt` file to

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6)
   project (c_speech_features)
   include(GNUInstallDirs)

   ### I ADDED THESE VARIABLES TO COMPILE FOR ANDROID ###
   set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
   set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 23)
   set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI armeabi-v7a)
   set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /path_to/android-ndk-r18b/)  

   option (ENABLE_DOUBLE "Enable double-precision floats" OFF)
   if (ENABLE_DOUBLE)
     set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Dkiss_fft_scalar=double")
   endif ()
   configure_file ("c_speech_features_config.h.in" "c_speech_features_config.h")

   add_library (objlib OBJECT c_speech_features.c kiss_fft130/kiss_fft.c kiss_fft130/tools/kiss_fftr.c)
   set_property (TARGET objlib PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1)

   include_directories (kiss_fft130 kiss_fft130/tools)

   add_library (c_speech_features SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>)
   add_library (c_speech_features_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>)
   ```
3. opened the source directory in terminal
4. ran `cmake`
5. ran `make`

However, no matter what I set the `ANDROID_ARCH_ABI` to, after running `cmake` and then `make` the ABI of the resulting `.so` library is always the same as when the above variables are not set in the `CMakeLists.txt` file. This is the result:

```
~$ readelf -h libc_speech_features.so | grep 'Class\|File\|Machine'
  Class:                             ELF64
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
```

I have attempted to do this on fresh downloads of the library repository and so do not think it is a problem with cached CMake files.

**Is it possible to create the `.so` library for the different ABI architectures in this way? If so how should I alter my approach?** If there is some other way to compile the libraries I would also be happy to try. Below are some other attempts I made.

### Edit after Tsyvarev comment

I have removed the set variables from the `CMakeLists.txt` file and am now attempting to use the toolchain file by running the command

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path_to/android-ndk-r18b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/path_to/android-ndk-r18b \
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=x86 \
.
```

I then run `make` to build the `.so` file. However now the resulting `.so` lib is always:

```
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:                           ARM
```

**Am I incorrectly setting the desired architecture? How is one supposed to alter the architecture when using the cmake toolchain?**

### Other Attempts

I have seen there are a number of other ways to include a C library in an Android application:

- I was unsuccessful in adding the C code directly and building the
  library using Android Studio ([docs description](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code)) as I could not
  access any of the methods. I'm sure its possible this way, but have now understood how to include and use pre-existing `.so` libs so creating one may be easier.
- [Android NDK standalone toolchains](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) I have not understood how to
  run on this C library with its `CMakeLists.txt` that defines how the
  library is built
- I've seen [android-cmake](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake) mentioned often and I may be being dumb
  here but could see how to use it from the README (its also quite old
  so may not be better than directly using cmake).
- I do not think using Android.mk is easier seeing as I have a library
  with the `CMakeLists.txt` file already and so converting it seems
  like more work

Comment: An .so file is built for whatever ABI it was built for; it's not something you change after the fact. If you want to build that library for other ABIs you need to build it from source. You mentioned that you were unsuccessful in doing so, but you haven't shown us exactly what you tried or which specific errors you ran into.

Comment: CMake [instructions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-android) you refers to are telling about **toolchain file**, which should be used via `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=...` option for `cmake`. Variable settings like `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)` shouldn't be used in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, they are for toolchain file.

Comment: I thought I was attempting to build it from source. I've maybe not been clear. I added the steps tried to show more clearly what I did.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I altered my answer to show where I am now stuck following your helpful pointer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841154/minimal-cmake-building-for-android/52843974#52843974

Comment: As far as I remember, a toolchain cannot use variables passed to the `cmake` executable via `-D` option. I suggest you to set all needed variables in the toolchain file itself. If this works, you may try to parametrize toolchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I incorrectly setting the desired architecture? How is one supposed to alter the architecture when using the cmake toolchain?

Yes. Unfortunately both Android and CMake added support for the other at the same time, so there are two workflows for this, and you're mixing and matching them.

For the best support for new NDKs, you want to use the NDK's builtin support (the toolchain file, like you're using), but you need to use the `ANDROID_*` variables rather than the `CMAKE_ANDROID_*` variables.

See the Android docs for CMake for a breakdown of the available flags: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.

To fix your specific invocation, you want:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path_to/android-ndk-r18b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DANDROID_ABI=x86 \
      .
```

(apparently `ANDROID_ABI` isn't listed in the first table since it's not something the user has to worry about when using CMake via gradle, but it is documented further down the page)

If you're using a pre-r18 NDK (you're not, but maybe someone else landing here will be) there are a few additional flags no longer listed on that page (such as `ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN`). There's a comment at the top of the toolchain file itself that lists all the options it supports if you need to go down that route.